# JPA : Update operation without JPA query or entitymanager

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am learning JPA, I found out that we have some functions which is already present in Jparepository like save,saveAll,find, findAll etc. but there is nothing like update,

I come across one scenario where I need to update the table, if the value is already present otherwise I need to insert the record in table.

I created

```
@Repository
public interface ProductInfoRepository
    extends JpaRepository<ProductInfoTable, String>
{
    Optional<ProductInfoTable> findByProductName(String productname);
}

public class ProductServiceImpl
    implements ProductService
{
    @Autowired
    private ProductInfoRepository productRepository;

    @Override
    public ResponseMessage saveProductDetail(ProductInfo productInfo)
    {
        Optional<ProductInfoTable> productInfoinTable =
            productRepository.findByProductName(productInfo.getProductName());
        ProductInfoTable productInfoDetail;
        Integer quantity = productInfo.getQuantity();
        if (productInfoinTable.isPresent())
        {
            quantity += productInfoinTable.get().getQuantity();
        }
        productInfoDetail =
            new ProductInfoTable(productInfo.getProductName(), quantity + productInfo.getQuantity(),
                                 productInfo.getImage());
        productRepository.save(productInfoDetail);
        return new ResponseMessage("product saved successfully");
    }
}
```

as you can see, I can save the record if the record is new, but when I am trying to save the record which is already present in table  it is giving me error related to primarykeyviolation which is obvious. I checked somewhat, we can do the update by creating the entitymanager object or jpa query but what if I dont want to use both of them. is there any other way we can do so ?

update I also added the instance of EntityManager and trying to merge the code

```
 @Override
    public ResponseMessage saveProductDetail(ProductInfo productInfo)
    {
        Optional<ProductInfoTable> productInfoinTable =
            productRepository.findByProductName(productInfo.getProductName());
        ProductInfoTable productInfoDetail;
        Integer price = productInfo.getPrice();
        if (productInfoinTable.isPresent())
        {
            price = productInfoinTable.get().getPrice();
        }
        productInfoDetail =
            new ProductInfoTable(productInfo.getProductName(), price, productInfo.getImage());
        em.merge(productInfoDetail);
        return new ResponseMessage("product saved successfully");
```

but no error, no execution of update statements in log, any possible reasons for that ?
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you need code like this to solve the problem

```
public ResponseMessage saveProductDetail(ProductInfo productInfo)
    {
        Optional<ProductInfoTable> productInfoinTable =
            productRepository.findByProductName(productInfo.getProductName());

        final ProductInfoTable productInfoDetail;
        if (productInfoinTable.isPresent()) {
            // to edit
            productInfoDetail = productInfoinTable.get();
            Integer quantity = productInfoDetail.getQuantity() + productInfo.getQuantity();
            productInfoDetail.setQuantity(quantity);
        } else {
            // to create new
            productInfoDetail = new ProductInfoTable(productInfo.getProductName(), 
                productInfo.getQuantity(), productInfo.getImage());
        }

        productRepository.save(productInfoDetail);
        return new ResponseMessage("product saved successfully");
    }
```

Comment: Strange behaviour. As you can see here  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L551 `save` method executes `persist` for new instances and `merge` for existing ones. Can you provide your entity class?

Comment: hey, dont know how, but working now. I was not aware this behaviour of save for repository in jpa. could you please edit your answer little bit so that i can upvote and mark this as answer